# Custom data type for boost property tree (inheriting string)

Tags: c++, boost, stdstring

I know this string business is a bad idea, but I have to know it anyways:

So I want to read an xml using property tree *while* storing it inside my own data type: a child of string. This is what I tried, but with no luck:

```
#include <string>
#include <boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>
#include <boost/property_tree/xml_parser.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost::property_tree;

class data_type: public string{
    public:
        using string::string;
        /* other stuff ... */
};

using namespace boost::property_tree;
typedef basic_ptree<string, data_type> node_tree;


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    node_tree pt;
    // ptree pt;
    //open xml and read information to pt
    std::string filepath;
    std::stringstream stream;

    try{
        filepath = argv[1];
    }
    catch(...){
        cout<<"Please enter a path!\n";
    }

    //to check if it can parse streams
    std::ifstream file(filepath);
    if(file){
        stream << file.rdbuf();
        read_xml(stream, pt);
        //print_tree(pt);
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

The code is runnable if you have boost. These are the errors thrown on compile time:

#1-
`/opt/homebrew/include/boost/property_tree/detail/xml_parser_read_rapidxml.hpp:47:40: error: no viable overloaded '=': pt_attr.data() = typename Ptree::key_type(attr->value(), attr->value_size());`

`note: candidate function (the implicit move assignment operator) not viable: no known conversion from 'typename basic_ptree<string, data_type>::key_type' (aka 'std::string') to 'data_type' for 1st argument`

#2-
`error: no matching conversion for functional-style cast from 'typename basic_ptree<string, data_type>::key_type' (aka 'std::string') to 'boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::string, data_type>': Ptree(typename Ptree::key_type(node->value(), node->value_size()))));`

Shouldn't these be solved with `using string::string` inside?

For your reference, [this](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/doc/html/property_tree/reference.html#header.boost.property_tree.xml_parser_hpp) is the api of `read_xml`. Am I not providing the correct istream object? If so, how do I solve it?

Pretty new to boost and modern cpp: please do tell me if I am doing something terribly wrong somewhere. Thanks a lot!

Comment: `: public string` is probably not a good idea. `std::string` is not designed to be inherited from. "The code is runnable" no, it is not. For one, there are no `#include` directives.

Comment: Instead of using :public string you could use : private string and in your class data_type do using std::string::size(); and so on.

Answer (score 0):

XML is ultimately a dressed-up bunch of strings, so the natural data type for `read_xml` is `basic_tree<string, string>`. You can use another data type, but you need it to be compatible with `std::string` both ways. Your `data_type` isn't, because `using string::string;` doesn't inherit `string`'s copy constructor. Assignment is not inherited either. You need to manually add at least

```
data_type(const std::string&);
dtata_type& operator=(const std::string&);
```